# How To get Vuze working on 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I Installed 14.04 on a new computer and after installing vuze it will not show getting started screen or do any searches. Vuze opens but after that absolutely nothing works.I have re-installed with the newest version from vuze with all updates done but still nothing. I ran vuze config and all is good there with open ports on both TCP and UDP. It is not a internet problem as vuze on my laptop which is running 12.04 still works perfectly.

Comment: You run it from terminal, Ctrl+Alt+t, run `vuze` or `azureus`

Answer (score 1):

I had installed `vuze` and had the same problem.

- Then I installed `azureus`, which effectively also seems to install vuze.
- After installing, hit the <kbd>super</kbd> then type `azureus`, you get vuze!

Anyway, as of now azureus/vuze works again. I must say I don't understand the relationship between azureus and vuze, but it did the trick for me. Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: Actually, both packages depend on each other. Just matter of `.desktop` file only azureus have one `/usr/share/applications/azureus.desktop` (no desktop file for vuze)